# Installing distcache on CentOS 6.3

Tags: linux, httpd, centos6, httpd.conf

I'm trying to re-build our server based on CentOS 6.3 and i can't seem to find the `distcache` rpm. I have it on my 5.8 CentOS:

```
[root@server]# yum list distcache
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, priorities
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: mirror.atlanticmetro.net
Installed Packages
distcache.i386                                     1.4.5-14.1                                     installed
[root@server]# rpm -qi distcache
Name        : distcache                    Relocations: (not relocatable)
Version     : 1.4.5                             Vendor: CentOS
Release     : 14.1                          Build Date: Sat 06 Jan 2007 07:02:14 AM GMT
Install Date: Sun 11 Oct 2009 02:51:22 PM GMT      Build Host: builder5.centos.org
Group       : System Environment/Daemons    Source RPM: distcache-1.4.5-14.1.src.rpm
Size        : 247063                           License: LGPL
Signature   : DSA/SHA1, Wed 04 Apr 2007 12:21:11 AM GMT, Key ID a8a447dce8562897
URL         : http://www.distcache.org/
Summary     : Distributed SSL session cache
Description :
The distcache package provides a variety of functionality for
enabling a network-based session caching system, primarily for
(though not restricted to) SSL/TLS session caching.
```

I need this package to enable the `mod_file_cache.so` mod.

I've tried googling without any success..

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Distcache was removed from EL6, according to the [package manifest](https://access.redhat.com/knowledge/docs/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/6/pdf/Package_Manifest/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux-6-Package_Manifest-en-US.pdf). Apparently it was not important enough to warrant a note in the [Migration Planning Guide](https://access.redhat.com/knowledge/docs/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/6/pdf/Migration_Planning_Guide/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux-6-Migration_Planning_Guide-en-US.pdf), though from visiting their web site I would guess the most likely reason is that it's [ancient and unmaintained](http://distcache.sourceforge.net/) and therefore unsupportable. Whatever you're trying to do, it's probably time to look at other options.